# KIVY "[CRITICAL] [Clock ] Warning" on_touch_move

Tags: kivy, drag

I have written a small code to drag widget horizontally using on_touch_move event. Even my widget moves horizontally. But when I am dragging the widget, following log gets generated."***[CRITICAL] [Clock       ] Warning, too much iteration done before the next frame. Check your code, or increase the Clock.max_iteration attribute***". 
Please find below my sample code. To reproduce this scenario, just drag the white widget right and left. The above log messages gets printed.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout


class MyPaintWidget(Scatter):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs) :
        super(MyPaintWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch_x_hint = touch.x / self.parent.size[0]
        self.pos_hint = {'center_x': touch_x_hint }
        return super(Scatter, self).on_touch_move(touch)

class MyPaintApp(App):

    def build(self):
        parent = RelativeLayout()

        Wdgt = MyPaintWidget(pos_hint={'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}, size_hint=(0.2,0.2))
        with Wdgt.canvas:
            Rectangle(pos_hint = {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}, size = (Wdgt.width, Wdgt.height))

        parent.add_widget(Wdgt)
        return parent

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems with your code. The first is that your `super()` call in `MyPaintWidget.on_touch_move()` should pass `MyPaintWidget`, not `Scatter`. Second, using `pos_hint` causes extra calculations, so I suggest changing your `on_touch_move()` to:

```
def on_touch_move(self, touch):
    self.pos_hint = {'center_y':0.5}  # eliminates the x pos_hint
    self.x = touch.x
    return super(MyPaintWidget, self).on_touch_move(touch)
```

Comment: Thanks. I still need solution based on pos_hint. When I commented self.pos_hint = {'center_x': touch_x_hint } no more warning is displayed. But obviously widget drag is not possible.

Comment: Are you saying that you don't get drag if you use the code in my answer?

Comment: Sorry. Your code works perfect. I wrong assumed that I should not use 'pos' if widgets are created using pos_hint. Your code works :-) Thanks a lot

Comment: You must be careful if you try using both. The `pos_hint` will over-ride settings for `pos`. That is why I included the code `self.pos_hint = {'center_y':0.5}` which eliminates the `pos_hint` for `x`.